# LibGit2Sharp log remote

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

Is there any way to list commits that have been fetched, but not merged using LibGit2Sharp?

For example I can run the following git command:

```sh
C:\Users\Tom\SourceLog>git log origin
commit f3beb4960b2f4bf5641d5b512b5b8c3081512a56
Author: Tom Hunter
Date:   Wed Jan 9 22:58:51 2013 +0000

    Rollback change to icon

    Seemed to crash on windows xp for some reason..

commit d95f29a6cbfea9cb6009c3095a67d71f86d9e8bd
Author: Tom Hunter
Date:   Mon Jan 7 21:34:36 2013 +0000

    Updating Icon

commit 8785ed4ff3c46bef46ea6e2398c115b4b0203b2c
Author: Tom Hunter
Date:   Mon Jan 7 21:22:54 2013 +0000

    Fixing tests

    Moved GenerateFlowDocuments method to LogEntry class.
    Have somehow managed to greatly simplify tests..

...
```

The top two commits have not yet been merged into my local repository.  I.e. this is what I get if I leave out **origin**:

```sh
C:\Users\Tom\SourceLog>git log
commit 8785ed4ff3c46bef46ea6e2398c115b4b0203b2c
Author: Tom Hunter
Date:   Mon Jan 7 21:22:54 2013 +0000

    Fixing tests

    Moved GenerateFlowDocuments method to LogEntry class.
    Have somehow managed to greatly simplify tests..

...
```

The following code gives me only 8785ed.  How can I get a list including the yet-to-be merged commits?

```cs
using (var repo = new Repository(@"C:\Users\Tom\SourceLog"))
{
    var c = repo.Commits.First();
}
```

Comment: You can try with `repo.Branches["origin"].Commits.First()`...

Comment: Thanks @nemesv, tried that and now I get: Failed to open 'C:/Users/Tom/SourceLog/.git/refs/remotes/origin': Access is denied.  I can open this directory in windows explorer. Any ideas?

Comment: As stated in the above answer the correct usage is: `repo.Branches["origin/HEAD"].Commits.First()`

Comment: Bingo - this works, thanks! (I'll accept if you add as an answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the commits of your remote origin branch with:

```
repo.Branches["origin/HEAD"].Commits
```

And you can use `First()` the get the latest commit by the default sorting. However you get all the commits of the remote branch not just the not merged one.

If you want to have a collection of the not merged commits you should use `QueryBy(filter)` to get the commits. [nulltoken's asnwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14296201/872395) described the solution but it contains an error. The correct usage is:

```
var filter = new Filter
{
    Since = repo.Branches["origin/HEAD"],
    Until = repo.Head
};
var notMergedCommits = repo.Commits.QueryBy(filter);
```

Because:

- Since: A pointer to a commit object or a **list of pointers to consider as starting points.**
- Until:  A pointer to a commit object or a **list of pointers which will be excluded** (along with ancestors) from the enumeration.

So with the above code you want to have the commits from the branch `"origin/HEAD"` and exclude the ones which are included in your `"HEAD"` which means return all the commits which are in the fetched branch and not yet merged to the `"HEAD"`.

Comment: You're right. I made a mistake. Thanks for having fixed it! Removing my answer in order to let yours shine under the sun ;-)