# origin/master VS origin/HEAD

Tags: git, libgit2sharp

I understand that origin/HEAD is usually pointing to remote origin/master branch. 
But I found a case in which these two are different.

In this thread -- [LibGit2Sharp log remote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14295805/libgit2sharp-log-remote), the answer is using `repo.Branches["origin/HEAD"]` not `repo.Branches["origin/master"]`.

Actually, when I tried to use `"origin/master"` instead of `"origin/HEAD"`, it didn't work. Seems like the `"origin/master"` is pointing to local repo branch, not remote repo branch. Just let you know that fetch is done before this step.

So why these two are different in this case?

Comment: `HEAD` is just the currently checked out commit/branch, in this case, on origin. The remote repository doesn't necessarily have to have `master` checked out. In your case, this seems the case.

Comment: @JeffMercado if I use '"origin/HEAD"', it will show me remote master's stuff. While I use "origin/master", it only shows local master stuff. so I don't agree with your case

Comment: You're mixing a number of dangerously tricky subjects: (1) symbolic refs, (2) `origin/HEAD`, and (3) libgit2sharp vs Git itself. I neither use nor have libgit2sharp but Git's treatment of both symbolic refs during clone, and `origin/HEAD` itself, has changed over various Git versions, so your server's Git version will matter, *and* whatever libgit2sharp does (and what version of Git it claims to be) will *also* matter.

Comment: @torek Yeah. I think you're right. I realize my question is not a good question.